# How to programmatically edit files in another branch even when there are uncommitted changes in the current branch?

Tags: git

As a personal exercise, I am writing a command line and git-based issue tracker where the issues are saved in another git branch (say, `project-issues`). Let's say I'm currently working on the `master` branch. With my issue tracker, running `issue-tracker --add-issue "Fix all bugs"` will need to modify the contents of the `project-issues` branch. So the question is: what is a recommended way to programmatically modify the contents of another branch (even if there are uncommited changes in the current branch)?

Possible methods I've thought of:

- The program runs `git stash` on the branch that the user is working on, switches to the `project-issues` branch, makes the required commits to the `project-issues` branch, switches back to the branch that the user was originally on, then runs `git stash apply`.
- The program creates a temporary working directory for the `project-issues` branch using git-workdir, makes the required commits in the temporary working directory, then deletes the temporary working directory.

Is there a simpler solution to this problem?

P.S. The program is written in Python.

Comment: The `git stash` and `git stash pop` is exactly how I would do it.

Comment: @Attersson Thanks. I've been looking at similar projects such as [ticgit](https://github.com/jeffWelling/ticgit/), but I couldn't figure out how they manage to keep the modifications to the user's branch intact.

Comment: Automated use of `git stash` is *not* a good idea.  Any solution that disturbs the working tree is dangerous for various reasons, the simplest of which is potential interaction with running development tools.  Using `stash` runs afoul of that problem, plus other weird edge cases peculiar to how stash works.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to be careful with having different branches in a repo have different content (rather than different versions of the same content).  What you describe *is* a reasonable use case for doing it, but still there are some things to watch out for.  Mostly I would suggest - if you aren't already  doing it this way - making sure that there are no commits in common between the issue history and the code history.  (i.e. the first issues branch would be created as an `orphan`, and any additional would be created from it)  This will help avoid potential merge mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [low-level plumbing commands](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_low_level_commands_plumbing) to create blobs, trees and commits.
E.g.:

1. `hash-object` would create a blob (from a file or stdin)
2. `mktree` to create a tree with the blob(s)
3. `commit-tree` to create a commit with the tree
4. `update-ref` to move a ref to the new commit

There is a small basic example [here](https://alx.github.io/gitbook/7_raw_git.html).

Another idea is to use `git notes` or at least just a ref (or orphaned branch) instead of regular branch to keep the issue information separate and independent from project files and branches.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest *avoiding* `git stash`.  It's full of sharp corner cases.

If you have `git worktree add`, use that.  It has a nasty bug from the point it first appeared (Git 2.5) until Git 2.15, which means you should complete any work you do in an added work-tree within two weeks and then delete the added work-tree, but if you're doing this in a program, you'll finish in minutes or at worst hours, not weeks.

The low-level method in [kan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59760564/1256452) will be the most efficient (by far) but requires understanding the internal details of Git, at least to some extent.

Answer (score -2):

If you using a Jenkinsfile pipeline with webhooks, You have better control on the custom tasks you want to execute, in any case if you are switching to another branch without commiting, You must stash it.